# JavaScript: Finding successive matches with .exec()

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match, exec

I have an object with a myriad of properties, such as color and brand, that describes a product.  I'm looking for a way to dynamically generate product descriptions in paragraph form (because API doesn't provide one), and I came up with a way to do so by writing "templates" that have "props" surrounded in brackets `{{}}`.  I wrote a function to "parse" the template by injecting the object properties in the string by replacing the "props" with the value of the key.

For example:

Object: `{color: 'white'}`

Template: `"The bowl is {{color}}."`

Result: `"The bowl is white."`

For some reason, my parse function isn't working.  `{{general_description}}` isn't parsed.

```js
var obj = {
  brand: "Oneida",
  general_description: "Plate",
  material: "China",
  color: "Bone White",
  product_width: "5\""
};

const templatePropRe = /{{(\w*)}}/g;
const parse = (template) => {
  while ((result = templatePropRe.exec(template)) !== null) {
    let match = result[0],
      key = result[1];
    template = template.replace(match, obj[key]);
  }
  return template;
}

console.log(parse('This {{color}}, {{material}} {{general_description}} supplied by {{brand}} has a width of {{product_width}}.'));
```

I followed the example provided in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) under Examples > Finding successive matches.  It says that I need to first store the regular expression in a variable (e.g., `templatePropRe`), for the expression cannot be in the while loop condition or it will loop indefinitely.  However, if I do that, my problem is resolved. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/MatthewKosloski/f8at9rzm/)...nothing broke.

I rewrote the function using [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), and it works as expected, but I don't have access to the capture so I need to first strip off the brackets using `stripBrackets`.  See the working example using `match` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/MatthewKosloski/w9d77aoh/).

What I want to know is why doesn't my `parse()` function that utilizes `RegExp.prototype.exec` work properly?

Comment: Please check my [single-pass approach below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47990731/3832970).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `/g` flag from your regex. According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), when this flag is present, it updates the regex object's `lastIndex` property which indicates from where next call to `exec()` will start to search a match.

```js
var obj = {
  brand: "Oneida",
  general_description: "Plate",
  material: "China",
  color: "Bone White",
  product_width: "5\""
};

const templatePropRe = /{{(\w*)}}/;
const parse = (template) => {
  while ((result = templatePropRe.exec(template)) !== null) {
    let match = result[0],
      key = result[1];
      
    template = template.replace(match, obj[key]);
  }
  
  return template;
}

console.log(parse('This {{color}}, {{material}} {{general_description}} supplied by {{brand}} has a width of {{product_width}}.'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened because you modify and check the same string in your code.
Whereas regExp saves index of matched substring after each execution you change length of the string and regEx with next execution starts from other point than you expect.

```js
var obj = {
  brand: "Oneida",
  general_description: "Plate",
  material: "China",
  color: "Bone White",
  product_width: "5\""
};

const templatePropRe = /{{(\w*)}}/g;
const parse = (template) => {
  var resultStr = template;
  while ((result = templatePropRe.exec(template)) !== null) {
    let match = result[0],
      key = result[1];
    resultStr = resultStr.replace(match, obj[key]);
  }
  return resultStr;
}

console.log(parse('This {{color}}, {{material}} {{general_description}} supplied by {{brand}} has a width of {{product_width}}.'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of performing the 2-step replacement (finding a match and then replacing the first occurrence with the required value) (that is prone with issues like the one you encountered when a new string is passed to the same RegExp with old, already invalid, index), you may use a [callback method as a replacement argument inside a `String#replace` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter). That way, the resulting string will be constructed on the fly upon each match making the code execute faster.

See an example fix below:

```js
var obj = {
  brand: "Oneida",
  general_description: "Plate",
  material: "China",
  color: "Bone White",
  product_width: "5\""
};
const parse = (template) => {
  return template.replace(/{{(\w*)}}/g, ($0, $1) => obj[$1] ? obj[$1] : $0 );
  // ES5 way:
  // return template.replace(/{{(\w*)}}/g, function($0, $1) {
  //       return obj[$1] ? obj[$1] : $0;
  // });
}

console.log(parse('{{keep}} This {{color}}, {{material}} {{general_description}} supplied by {{brand}} has a width of {{product_width}}.'));
```

Note that here, after finding a match, the `($0, $1) => obj[$1] ? obj[$1] : $0` code does the following: the whole match is assigned to `$0` variable and the Group 1 value is assigned to `$1`; then, if there is a key with the name `$1` in `obj`, the value will be put instead of the match into the right place in the resulting string. Else, the whole match is put back (replace with `''` if you want to remove a `{{...}}` with a non-existent key name).

Comment: I like this better than what I did.  I will use this instead--thanks!